# Android how to create activity only if it wasn't created yet

Tags: android

I have a problem cause when I go to different activities using startActivity function,
they always get created from scratch. Even if activity A was visited before, when I go to activity B and then A again, activity A is created again.

The problem is with back button, cause if I go to Activity A then B then A and then B,
in order to close the application I have to press back button 4 times.
I guess that it shouldn't act like it and user should be able to go to activity A when first pressed back button and the second press should close the application.

How to solve this issue?
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried solutions proposed so far, however they didn't do it for me.
What did however, is using flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** while starting activities.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have activity transitions like:

Activity A -> Activity B
Activity B -> Activity A

and you want the user to go back to the same instance of Activity A in this case, maybe you just need to call finish() in Activity B after you call startActivity() for Activity A?

If this isn't helpful, please give us more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you implement `onSaveInstanceState` and be prepared to restore your activity from a `Bundle` in `onCreate`. that's how you re-establish where you were when you return to an activity.

Answer (score 0):

add launcheMode="singleTask" to your activity in the manifest

Comment: This isn't the right solution at all. Changing the launchMode is a bad idea unless you have a very unusual application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to your intent for launching activity A. Doing so will cause your previously created activity to re-use. Make sure you do handle your afterwards intents in `onNewIntent` method. [For more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: This won't help in the poster's situation. He says he goes from Activity A to Activity B then to Activity A. In this case, when launching Activity A from Activity B: even if Activity A was started with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` it would still create a new instance of Activity A because Activity A is NOT at the top of the activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** when you start activity A from B or vice versa, like

```
i = new Intent("....ActivityAorB");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```